# Get the sum of product of 2 position values in every list within a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that contains lists in it like the one below:

```
a = {'Dairy-Milk': ['Dairy-Milk', '12345', '800', 1], 'test': ['test', '1111', '600', 1]}
```

I want to go through the dictionary perform multiplication for (each_dictionary_Item[2] * each_dictionary_Item[3]) then get the total sum from all the items.

From my little knowledge, I have called a.get_keys then I have gone through for each item in the key,and called list pos 2 * 3, then appended that to another list in which I get the sum of the entire list using sum(list)....this gives me incorrect sums when new items are added.

```
 for item in self.listofKeys:
            thequantity = self.productList[item][3]
            thecash = self.productList[item][2]
            multiplied = float(thequantity) * float(thecash)
            self.thesumsList.append(multiplied)

        self.ids.thetotal.text = "Total Payable: " + str(sum(self.thesumsList))
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I want? (get sum of every item in list list[3] * list[3])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: iterate over the values themselves, pulling out the desired product from each.  Feed that result to `sum` directly as a *generator*.

```
sum(entry[2] * entry[3] for entry in a.values())
```